# Merge http request on node red

Tags: node-red

I need to create a request with a dynamic url (ID I get from http endpoint) and a body I build based on a response from another webservice.

The problem is that I get this information from two different nodes, how can I merge this information and send the request?

Should I create a flow variable? In this case how can I use it in the http request node as url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just chain the http-request nodes together with a change node between them to stash the result from the first one on a different key than `msg.payload`.

You will also need to use the change node to delete `msg.headers` between the http-request nodes.

As for the URL, if you leave that field empty in the http-request node's config it can use the value of `msg.url` that is passed in.